# Call custom order meta in woocommerce email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom fields in the checkout in woocommerce and I want these fields to appear in the email template.

I am adding the following but it still not showing:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $mycustom = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'wccf_delivery_day', true );
            echo $mycustom;?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can make use of `woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys` filter hook

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys');

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {

    $keys['Delivery Day'] = '_wccf_delivery_day';

    return $keys;

}
```

If you need more control over the display try using `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` action hook

```
add_action( "woocommerce_email_after_order_table", "custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table", 10, 1);

function custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table( $order ) {

    echo '<p><strong>Delivery Day :</strong>'. get_post_meta( $order->id, "_wccf_delivery_day", true ) .'</p>';

}
```

Comment: Hey, I was looking for weeks for a solution to this problem - where did you find this code?  Is it documented somewhere that I've overlooked?

Comment: That seems to work for Processing Order emails, but not for Order Complete emails?